# Access Find & Replace Tool Without Template Warning

Tags: templates, editor

When saving a template with a syntax error, EE will issue a warning, with a link to a Find & Replace utility.

[image]

This utility is super handy, but only seems to be available when there is a problem (usually an open-ended tag pair). Is there any way to access this, normally?

I can't seem to find anything about it in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This utility is not available outside the location where you are seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The [search and replace tool](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/search_and_replace.html) can be found at Tools > Data > Search and Replace.  The available options are:

- Site Preferences
- Channel Entry Titles
- Channel Fields
- Templates

Comment: I am aware of that. It's not what I'm looking for. The utility in the template editor has Find, Find Next, Replace, and Replace All options, whereas the Search and Replace is a blanket Replace All.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the only a know about.